# How can I keep the action bar button clicks consistent among different activities. (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Here is my question, and I'm sure its a basic one.  please be patient with me since its been over 2 years since I've programmed.

I created an Action bar in my `MainActivity` class.  In my `onOptionsItemsSelected`(Main menu) method, I have a switch statement that tells MainActivity which activity to start based on user input from the action items that are available. I am interested in having the `Action Bar` maintain consistent behavior across all activities when the user chooses a selection.  The menu items stay the same, I want to have the `onOptionsItemsSelected` be the same across all activities.  I could copy and paste the code from MainActivity, but I know that isn't the 'correct' way to do it.

For example:
In MainActivity action bar gives option A,B,C.  Activity A,B, or C starts when user selects it.

If a user selects A, A starts.  I want to user to be able to start B,C or main screen using the action bar.

I know that this has a basic solution, but its been a while since I've coded.  All help is appreiated.  Feel free to be snarky due to the simplicity of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, and it comes down to basic programming.  Please let me know if this comes out clear enough.

So there are a few things to know about the Android format of programming.  From MainActivity(), when it starts it calls two functions in order:

OnCreateOptionsMenu(Item item) which calls the values to put in the menu / action bar.
OnOptionsItemsSelected(Item item) which tells the Application what to do with the selection.

If you want to keep the action bar consistent across each of the different views, in each activity when you call OnOptionsItemsSelected(), you have the method that gets the id from the choice, then you return it using super.OnOptionsItemsSelected(item).  In order for this to work, the user should have the calling class extend MainActivity instead of Activity.  Here is an example of the code:

This is the code from a 2nd activity that wants to keep the same behaving action bar (with the same choices) that MainActivity has.  Note: if you don't extend MainActivity it won't work because it will call the method from Activity class, not your MainActivity.

```
public class secondActivity extends MainActivity{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   
    }

}
```